# UIScrollView: override the addition of pan/pinch gesture recognizers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview, gesture-recognition

I want to make a custom `UITextView` that functions exactly like the standard text view but extends just a `UIView` without any gesture recognizers . Since a `UIScrollView` is basically a `UIView` with added gesture recognizers I figured this is just a matter of overriding the method of `UITextView`, inherited from `UIScrollView`, in which the view has gesture recognizers added to it. Does anyone know which methods these are so my custom text view can skip adding a pan and pinch gesture recognizer altogether? Right now, I have my custom textview remove all of its gesture recognizers upon initialization which seems icky on the performance end.

Comment: Why don't you create the same gesture recognisers and add to the text view, invalidation the original ones?

Comment: I want a text view with absolutely no gesture recognizers. I mean my solution now is I disabled them all. But it would nicer if they weren't even added in the first place